# Authenticate from HTML to Salesforce with out using sites

Tags: force.com

I have a external web page with html page .

html page contains a button and an email.

when i click that button  i need to post the email to sales force (apex class or trigger or anything )
i need to access that email value into sales force with out using site.com.

Please let me know  as early as possible.

Comment: There are various [OAUTH flows](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) available; do any of these work for you?

Comment: If the use case is that you want a copy processed into the SF Database, you could create an inbound email service to process the email. Its not clear from your post whether you want SF to send the email for you or whether you just want to import a copy of into your database.